# Unable to open Gecko Driver with RSelenium package in R without using Docker

Tags: r, selenium, geckodriver, browser-automation, rselenium

I am unable to connect to the Selenium server.

I'm using RSelenium to automate data collection for a school project.
What baffles me is that it has worked every day for two weeks now, but I restarted my macbook so had to reconnect to the Selenium server, and now I can't make it run.
I've tried reinstalling firefox, the geckodriver, the selenium standalone server, and tried running it with chrome.

I've put this in the terminal:
`java -jar /Users/x/data/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 5556`

This is what I do in R:
`remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE), port=5556)
remDr$open()`

I get this error message when running `remDr$Open()`:

> Selenium message:Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>   System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-3.local', ip: '[sensitive info removed]', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '11.0.2'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>
> Error:      Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
>        Detail: A new session could not be created.
>        Further Details: run errorDetails method

I am able to run it with Docker and Tight VNC, but sadly this throws a lot of errors as I need to use the debug version for my data collection.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm never seen this type of error before. @jdharrison can you look at this?